# Incorrect tagging of questions about [mesh-network] with [mesh] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I was\am seeing a bunch of questions related to mesh networks that are incorrectly tagged with [mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mesh) as opposed to (or in addition to) the correct one [mesh-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mesh-network).

Recently, I had an [approved wiki-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23244955) (hooray!) which discourages the use of [mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mesh) for such questions. To complete this small initiative, a bunch of questions has to be retagged.

Using a question search request [[mesh]+ network](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmesh%5D+network+is%3Aquestion&mixed=0), I got 42 results, out of which most are the incorrectly tagged questions.
I was able to identify only 4 questions from this list that should keep [mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mesh):

- [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20626801/2452869)
- [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36708650/2452869)
- [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54148465/2452869)
- [Q4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57415713/2452869)

Can we retag the remaining 38 to [mesh-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mesh-network), without me clogging up the suggested edits queue?

Reasons why I care: I follow the RSS feed for the [mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mesh), as well as several others related to computational sciences.

Comment: Technically this isn't possible as such. There isn't any tool to automatically replace a tag, both CM/non-CM. The CM tool for retagging supports the addition of a new tag for a set of questions.  So if we need to do this, it'll have to be done manually by a 2k+ user.

Comment: @BhargavRao shame on me not contributing to SO enough.

Comment: Well, there are other users in the community willing to help out, so you needn't be too hard on yourself. Once we get consensus from everyone that doing this would be a good idea, we can start working on it.